# Pushforward and integral curves

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have been studying for an exam and I managed to forget elementary stuff concerning pushforwards and I want to clarify some intuition. Let's say I have a Lie group $G$ and its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. I will denote conjugation with $g \in G$ as $I_g$, so $I_g h = ghg^{-1}$ for some $h \in G$. If I have the following

$$Ad_g(X) = I_{g*}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp(tX) =\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g \exp(tX)g^{-1},  $$

where $X \in \mathfrak{g}$. I understand the first equality, which comes simply from the fact how the exponential and the adjoint representation are defined, however I can't grasp why the second equality works. If I look at the definition of the pushforward which would be for some $\phi: M \to N$, where $M, N$ are smooth manifolds and $Y \in T_pM$ for $p \in M$:

$$\phi_*(Y)f  = Y(f \circ \phi).$$

How do these two things come together? I feel like I should be thinking of $Y$ as "derivatives of curves that pass trough $p$" and somehow rewriting this condition for pushforward. Does

$$\phi_*(Y) =\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\phi(\gamma(t))$$

hold if $\gamma$ is integral curve of $Y$, such that $\gamma(p)$ = 0. If it does hold, why is that the case? It looks like I am missing something very trivial in all of this.

Comment: I think you are talking about a matrix Lie group.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Definition) there is the full proof. I'm not sure if it holds for general Lie groups

Comment: It holds for all Lie groups, but you must write $L_{g*}v$ instead of $gv$.